# Inviting Friends on Event throws OAuthException

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, invite

I am trying to invite the friends of the logged in facebook user to a certain event by using following code:-

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
       message : user.name + " has invited you to an event",
      title : "Invite friends to go along with you",
      },function(response){
        for(i=0;i<response.to.length;i++){
            FB.api('/'+eventId+'/invited/'+user.id,'post',function(resp){
            alert(resp);});
        }
      });
```

But I am receiving this error

```
error:{"message":"(#200) ","type":"OAuthException","code":200}
```

I have create_event, manage_pages, publish_stream, photo_upload permissions from the user. Could anyone provide me pointer where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/312375168858626?browse=search_5017eadead76b7a22667493

Facebook addresses bugs when developers complain about them. At the link above you should report that you are experiencing the same problem as the author.